# android-keyboard does not appear in child activity of TabActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

Code snippet:

```
public class home extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener{

private static final String HOME_SPEC = "";
private static final String PROFILE_SPEC = "";
private static final String NEWPOST_SPEC = "";
private static final String SETTINGS_SPEC = "";
private TabHost tabHost; 
private TextView header;
int s,c;
private Typeface tf;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    tabHost = getTabHost();

    TabSpec newpostSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(NEWPOST_SPEC);
    newpostSpec.setIndicator(NEWPOST_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_post_tab));
    Intent newpostIntent = new Intent(home.this,NewPostActivity.class);
    newpostSpec.setContent(newpostIntent);

    tabHost.addTab(loginSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(newpostSpec);

    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        }

       }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

}
```

Above code i have used for TabActivity.Now in NewPostActivity I have only one edittext & when I click on Edittext ,Keyboard not appears to write in that edittext.
So What should I have to do for appearance of keyboard?
Please reply....

Answer (score 0):

```
For showing the keyboard implicitly do like this

// for showing the soft keyboard on click of edit text
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)     getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    // only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
    mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);


and to hide the keyboard it when touched somewhere outside of the edit text.

rel.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)     getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

here rel is the top layout in the xml

Comment: thanks for response...but its not working....I am facing problem in android2.3.6 version...& in android4.0 its working perfect... :(